# Blob images does not show up at UI, although I can see them on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, html5-canvas, blob

I am trying to create multiple blob images, and show them for a video timeline UI. To create the images, I take screenshots of the video for some certain time frames, and create img elements, then add img.src as blob images' url. The problem is **blob images does not show up at UI, although I can see them on console**. Any ideas?

Code snippet from creation of blob images:

```
// draw the video frame to canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.canvas.toBlob(
    blob => {
        resolve(blob);
    },
    "image/jpeg",
    0.75 /* quality */
);
```

Code Snippet from creation of images:

```
let img = '';
for (let i = 0; i < count / 3; i++) {
    const cover = await GetVideoCover(item.video_url, i);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(cover);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    img += "<img src='"+image.src+"'>";
    console.log(img)
}
return img;
```

The console log from `console.log(img)`line:

[image]

actual html img elements:

[image]

When I manually update the source as below, it works, but I did not understand why it does not get the source by itself. Any idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the contributions, the answers did not work but they helped me in the process. I solved the problem today and wanted to share it here.

1. I should have mentioned before as the created images are fed to `vis.js`.
2. When I experimented more, I saw vis.js does not append the created objects, but it changes the innerHTML of the timeline. (vis.js might not support blob images as src of img tag)
3. Then, I decided to give a shot to append element. To do that, I created a new div element, and appended the created images to that div.
4. I also added an additional promise level to the blob image creation process, since some files were missing.

Code snippet from newly added promise level:

```
const blobToImage = (itemVideoURL,captureSecond) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=> {
        let cover = await GetVideoCover(itemVideoURL,captureSecond);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(cover)
        let img = new Image()
        img.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        resolve(img)
        }
        img.src = url
        img.height = '75'
    })
}
```

Code snippet from new function:

```
let divElement  = document.createElement('div');
for (let i = 0; i < count * 3; i++) {
    let newImage = await blobToImage(item.video_url,i+1)
    divElement.appendChild(newImage)
}
return divElement;
```

It magically worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try registering an `onload` event listener on the `image` element and then handle all code that depends on that image in the event listener, like so:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < count / 3; i++) {
    const cover = await GetVideoCover(item.video_url, i);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(cover);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    // perform some magic here e.g append to DOM or draw the image to canvas
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a single image rather than multiple images.

Just concatanate all images together :

```
   let imgEle1 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[0];
   let imgEle2 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[1];
   let resEle = document.querySelector(".result");
   var context = resEle.getContext("2d");
   let BtnEle = document.querySelector(".Btn");
   BtnEle.addEventListener("click", () => {
   resEle.width = imgEle1.width;
      resEle.height = imgEle1.height;
      context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
      context.drawImage(imgEle1, 0, 0);
      context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      context.drawImage(imgEle2, 0, 0);
   });
```